# Can I configure my app with Configuration Profiles?

Tags: iphone, ios, configuration

I find Configuration Profiles an easy way to configure some system level settings of iPhone. Can I extend these settings somehow that I could use the same infrastructure (XML file format, profile signing, mime-type/extension recognizer on iPhone, etc) for configuring the settings of my own app?

I am aware of Mobile Device Management capabilities of iPhone and that it (probably) could be used for this but it seems overly complicated compared to Configuration Profiles.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not possible.

Comment: What a pity ... it would be too nice :)